# Logic problem: Atiyah-Macdonald 1.11

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Proposition 1.11 in Atiyah-Macdonald's "Introduction to commutative algebra" states the following:

"Given an ideal $I$ in a ring $A$ and $p_1, \dots p_n$ prime ideals, then $I \subset \cup_i p_i$ implies that $I\subset p_j$ for some $j\in \{1, \dots, n\}.$ "

This is clearly equivalent to saying that "if $I$ is not a subset of $p_i$ for any $i,$ then $I$ is not a subset of $\cup_i p_i.$"

But they then claim that this last statement is logically equivalent to the following:

"For each $i,$ there exists $x_i \in I$ such that $x_i \notin p_k$ for all $k\neq i.$"

Can anyone help me to see why this statement is logically a consequence of the first?  I know this is elementary, but I'm truly stuck and I'm hoping that someone can phrase things in a way that makes them more transparent.

Comment: If this is not hold for some $i$ then $I\subset \cup_{k, k\neq i}p_k$, and in this case $I\subset \cup_{k,k\neq i }p_k$ (reduction to $n-1$ prime ideals) .

Comment: Thanks so much. (Yikes, I guess this was obvious, but I was honestly stuck so I appreciate the help:))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence you are citing, "For each $i$, there exists $x_i\in I$ such that $x_i\notin p_k$ for all $k\neq i$", is not the logical negation of the statement, but the application of induction. That is, they assume that the statement is true for $n-1$ prime ideals and are applying to all subsets of size $n-1$ of $\{p_1,\ldots, p_n\}$, i.e., the set of the form $\{p_j\,|\,j\neq i\}$ with $i$between $1$ and $n$

Answer (score 1):

They do not really claim that "$I$ not in $p_i$ for every $i$ implies $I$ not in $\cup_i p_i$" **(1)** is logically equivalent to "For each $i,$ there exists $x_i \in I$ such that $x_i \notin p_k$ for all $k\neq i.$"**(2)**. First of all, you haven't specified what $k$, so how could these two be equivalent?

What is trully happening is that in trying to prove **(1)**, they use **(2)** in an induction argument. In particular, they assume that the statement is true whenever we have $n-1$ prime ideals. So suppose that $I \not\subset \cup_{i=1}^n p_i$. Then certainly for every $k= 1, ..., n$ we have that $I \not\subset \cup_{j \neq k} p_j$. Then apply the induction hypothesis to get **(2)**.